How to reproduce a bug in the ce-mftfmagento-commands.json?
After passing the archive with my extension to the Magento marketplace on technical review I got a ce-mftfmagento-commands.json with following error.
my environment: php:8.2 / mageno:2.4.7
test name: AddConfigurableProductToOrderFromShoppingCartTest
some steps before failure:
[selectOption1] select option "//\*[@id='product-options-wrapper']//div[@class='fieldset']//label[contains(.,'')]/../div[@class='control']//select","4"
[fillProductQuantity] fill field "input.input-text.qty","1"
[fillProductQuantityWaitForPageLoad] wait for page load 30
[waitForAddToCartButtonToRemoveDisabledState] wait for element not visible "#product-addtocart-button[disabled]",60
[waitForAddToCartButtonToRemoveDisabledStateWaitForPageLoad] wait for page load 60
[waitForAddToCartButton] wait for element clickable "#product-addtocart-button"
[waitForAddToCartButtonWaitForPageLoad] wait for page load 60
[clickOnAddToCartButton] click "#product-addtocart-button"
[clickOnAddToCartButtonWaitForPageLoad] wait for page load 60
[] javascript ERROR(SEVERE) - http://magento2.docker/static/version1734077859/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js 97:22 Uncaught Error: [object Object]
[saveScreenshot] save screenshot

echo after fail:
In AllureHelper.php line 29:
\[Exception\]

Exception trace:
at /app/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Allure/AllureHelper.php:29
Magento\\FunctionalTestingFramework\\Allure\\AllureHelper::addAttachmentToCurrentStep() at /app/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Extension/TestContextExtension.php:333
Magento\\FunctionalTestingFramework\\Extension\\TestContextExtension-\>attachExceptionToAllure() at /app/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/Extension/TestContextExtension.php:142
Magento\\FunctionalTestingFramework\\Extension\\TestContextExtension-\>testEnd() at /app/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:206
Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher-\>callListeners() at /app/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:56
Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher-\>dispatch() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Test.php:229
Codeception\\Test\\Test-\>realRun() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Suite.php:130
Codeception\\Suite-\>run() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:151
Codeception\\SuiteManager-\>run() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:260
Codeception\\Codecept-\>runSuite() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:216
Codeception\\Codecept-\>run() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:435
Codeception\\Command\\Run-\>execute() at /app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:326
Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command-\>run() at /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1078
Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application-\>doRunCommand() at /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:324
Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application-\>doRun() at /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:175
Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application-\>run() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Application.php:112
Codeception\\Application-\>run() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/app.php:45
{closure}() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/app.php:46
require() at /app/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:7
include() at /app/vendor/bin/codecept:119

I found out that Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js 97:22 can be get bad response from https://localhost/customer/section/load/?sections=cart,directory-data,messages&force_new_section_timestamp=true&_=1734353740160
but it not reproduce for me. I pass a test flow without errors.
Also, I tried to disable the following code from setCookiePath but nothing changed.
if (!preg_match('/SameSite/', $path)) {
    $path .= '; SameSite=None';
    $this->setOption('session.cookie_path', $path);
}

Could you tell me how I can fix this bug to pass a test on the Magento marketplace?

You should be able to follow the steps in the "steps before failure" to reproduce the error yourself locally, eg: fill a field, click a button. Then you can actually investigate what the error is and what causes it.
